# Problem converting the standard form of a quadratic to its vertex form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

After completing the square, doing so:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out why are we taking $f\left( -\frac{b}{2a}\right)$ afterwards.

Comment: It is should be apparent after completing the square. What is the minimum value of $x^2$ as $x$ varies? Can you abstract this to answer your question? Do you know what a vertex is?

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $f\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right)=\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$, which is just a concise way of detailing the relationship between the coefficients of a quadratic function and the location of its vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertex is the point where the minimum of the function occurs. For a function of the form $f(x) = a(x - h)^2 + k$, the minimum occurs at $(x - h)^2 = 0 \implies x = h.$ To find the $y$-coordinate of the vertex, we hence compute $f(h)$ where $h = \frac{-b}{2a}$.

An alternate way of thinking about this is through transformations. $x^2$ has a vertex at $(0, 0)$. If we map $x^2 \longrightarrow a(x - h)^2$, we shift the vertex to the right by $h$ units. The vertical dilation does not impact the vertex since $y = 0$. Then mapping $a(x - h)^2 \longrightarrow a(x - h)^2 + k$, we shift the vertex vertically up by $k$ units, which makes its coordinates $(h, k)$ where $k = \frac{4ac - b^2}{4a}$.